# Remove Ionic Environment http_proxy

Tags: ionic-framework, proxy, http-proxy

Hai In my ionic project i need to clear http_proxy
[image]

I have tried below options... But nothing works..

**npm rm http-proxy**

**npm config rm http_proxy**

**npm config delete proxy -g**

**npm config delete http_proxy -g**

**npm config delete https_proxy -g**

**set HTTP_PROXY=null**

How to remove this...

Answer (score 2):

Use this command

```
unset HTTP_PROXY
```

&

```
unset http_proxy
```